# HAXM Install Error on Windows XP

Tags: android-studio, windows-xp, haxm

I am attempting to setup/use Android Studio and am not able to get an AVD to work.  In the SDK Manager, it says that 'Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer)' has been installed.  When I try to start an AVD, I receive an error stating that 'HAX kernel module is not installed'.  I have tried running the HAXM install EXE as Administrator, which, results in an error stating the 'computer does not support VT-x'.  I have downloaded HAXM R2 and run it as administrator with the same results.  I have looked at the BIOS, but, do not see anything regarding hardware acceleration.  I have setup an AVD using 'Google APIs(x86 System image) API 19, tried using gpu and using snapshot.  This AVD gets the same error as all others I've tried.  Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated!

IBM T43 laptop
Intel Centrino processor
Windows XP SP3
I know that it is old and should be replaced, but, I am poor and trying to work with what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Current HAXM isn't supported on XP and you'll need to check your CPU's capabilities to see if Virtualization and XD bit are supported.